# Clip raster with another raster (by extent) in Python

Tags: python, clip, extents, numpy

I'm trying to do raster algebra with two rasters, but when I transform the rasters to array I can't do the operation because the files do not have the same extent

example:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

IMG1 = gdal.Open('C:/IMG1.TIF')
IMG2 = gdal.Open('C:/IMG2.TIF')

img1 = IMG1.ReadAsArray()
img2 = IMG2.ReadAsArray()

img1+img2
>>>>> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5353,3352) (5548,3232)
```

So.. if I see the gt of every img show that img1 and img2 have the same size of the pixel (100) but different extent

```
g1 = IMG1.GetGeoTransform()
gt1
>>>>> (482084.999999999, 100.0, 0.0, 5652715.00001374, 0.0, -100.0)
g2 = IMG2.GetGeoTransform()
gt2
>>>>> (475184.999999999, 100.0, 0.0, 5643715.00001535, 0.0, -100.0)
```

So.. I used this operation in order to get the intersect extent.. but I don't know how to apply

```
r1 = [gt1[0], gt1[3],gt1[0] + (gt1[1] * IMG1.RasterXSize), gt1[3] + (gt1[5] * IMG1.RasterYSize)]
r2 = [gt2[0], gt2[3],gt2[0] + (gt2[1] * IMG2.RasterXSize), gt2[3] + (gt2[5] * IMG2.RasterYSize)]
intersection = [max(r1[0], r2[0]), min(r1[1], r2[1]), min(r1[2], r2[2]), max(r1[3], r2[3])]
```

Comment: You need to get those coordinates into row, column addressing for both images (they will be different as they have different origins), then use ReadAsArray *with parameters* to read the common extent. When you write out as a new raster you need to adjust the geoTransform to the intersection extent created with the rows and columns of the intersection extent. Have a look at https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html in the section Calculate zonal statistics for an example of parameter reading as array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution

```
 #IN ORDER TO CLIP BY EXTENT EVERY IMAGE
    gt1=IMG1.GetGeoTransform()
    gt2=IMG2.GetGeoTransform()
    if gt1[0] < gt2[0]: #CONDITIONAL TO SELECT THE CORRECT ORIGIN
        gt3=gt2[0]
    else:
        gt3=gt1[0]
    if gt1[3] < gt2[3]:
        gt4=gt1[3]
    else:
        gt4=gt2[3]
    xOrigin = gt3
    yOrigin = gt4
    pixelWidth = gt1[1]
    pixelHeight = gt1[5]

    r1 = [gt1[0], gt1[3],gt1[0] + (gt1[1] * IMG1.RasterXSize), gt1[3] + (gt1[5] * IMG1.RasterYSize)]
    r2 = [gt2[0], gt2[3],gt2[0] + (gt2[1] * IMG2.RasterXSize), gt2[3] + (gt2[5] * IMG2.RasterYSize)]
    intersection = [max(r1[0], r2[0]), min(r1[1], r2[1]), min(r1[2], r2[2]), max(r1[3], r2[3])]

    xmin = intersection[0]
    xmax = intersection[2]
    ymin = intersection[3]
    ymax = intersection[1]

    # Specify offset and rows and columns to read
    xoff = int((xmin - xOrigin)/pixelWidth)
    yoff = int((yOrigin - ymax)/pixelWidth)
    xcount = int((xmax - xmin)/pixelWidth)+1
    ycount = int((ymax - ymin)/pixelWidth)+1
    srs=IMG1.GetProjectionRef() #necessary to export with SRS

    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', xcount, ycount, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((xmin, pixelWidth, 0,ymax, 0, pixelHeight,))


    img1 = IMG1.ReadAsArray(xoff, yoff, xcount, ycount)  
    img2 = IMG2.ReadAsArray(xoff, yoff, xcount, ycount)
```

Comment: I'm not qute sure, what are you doing with the target_ds? With the script as stanalone the srs and target_ds lines are leading to nothing. Probably you can add the rest of the script to make it complete.