# Using Rasterio to work with two rasters of different extent and resolution?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I have two spatial rasters of different extent and different cell size and I want to do a conditional statement with them. I decided to use rasterio for that. I use this code:

```
with rasterio.open('A.tif') as src:
A = src.read()

with rasterio.open('B.tif') as src:
B = src.read()

C = np.where ((A == 2) & (B == 1), 1, 0)
```

This is the error message:

> operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,982,1042)
>   (1,701,851)

What is the method to deal with this?

Comment: It looks like your rasters might incompatible shapes/sizes. You have to clip one or extend the other.... then run your raster arithmetic with numpy

Comment: okay thanks for that reply. but there is not a python module I can use that makes that automatically? And I think the rasters also have different cell sizes. How do I deal with that?

Comment: `rasterio` is the highest level python module for raster based operations that I know of. You have to deal with all that stuff (cell size, extent etc) yourself. You can't just pop in two numpy arrays and expect for the geospatial stuff to be done automatically. The line `C = np.where ((A == 2) & (B == 1), 1, 0)` has no GIS awareness whatsoever. It is  a pure numpy operation

Comment: okay, thx. I will do my research on these two issues and will post the solution here afterwards.

Comment: @Leo I am stacked on the issue. We need to resample one raster in order to be compared with the other one... I wonna downscaling the lower resolution raster in order to be compared with the higher resolution raster.

Comment: So the size issue can easily be solved with this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234226/clip-raster-with-another-raster-by-extent-in-python